# How to append a string to session storage keys?

Tags: javascript, session

I want to append the string to keys in session storage  i tried below code but it is not working

```
var setSession = window.sessionStorage.setItem.bind(window.sessionStorage);

window.onload = function()
{
  window.sessionStorage.setItem = function(key, value) {
            var newKey = "1234"+"::"+key;
            alert("inside account new key "+newKey);

            return setSession(newKey, value);
        }

}
```

Any suggestions more appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're after by using `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` but here's how to add a prefix to the `key` and don't do it again if the prefix already exists. Additionally it removes the original keys:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key) {
  if(/^1234::/.test(key)) return; // Don't repeat if "1234::" exists already
  localStorage[`1234::${key}`] = localStorage[key];
  delete localStorage[key];
});
```

if the prefix `1234` is a variable than you could do it like:

```
let ID_key = '1234';

Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key) {
  if(new RegExp(`^${ID_key}::`).test(key)) return; // Don't repeat if 1234 exists already
  localStorage[`${ID_key}::${key}`] = localStorage[key];
  delete localStorage[key];
});
```

Comment: if i want to pass as variable like `var id = "1234::"` for the same .

Comment: @zack here you go :)

Comment: thanks. and do you know how to make sessions not to share in same browser.

Comment: i want to make two different logins in same  browser for this service [this](https://slack.com/signin) something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig?hl=en). suppose in first tab if logged in second tab it should not share the session.

Comment: @zack not sure what session you're talking about... the "session ID" 1234? Two tabs on a same domain share the same `sessionStorage`. So yeah... the value will be equal on both tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you want to change the key of an item in session storage?

You could try using the code below.

```js
function changeKey(oldKey, newKey) {
    var item = sessionStorage.getItem(oldKey)
    sessionStorage.setItem(newKey, item)
    sessionStorage.removeItem(oldKey)
}
```

If you wanted to append a string, you could use this instead:

```js
function appendToKey(oldKey) {
    var item = sessionStorage.getItem(oldKey)
    oldKey = '1234' + '::' + oldKey
    sessionStorage.setItem(newKey, item)
    sessionStorage.removeItem(oldKey)
}
```

Comment: From where you are getting old key ? and where do i need to pass this `appendToKey ` function?

Comment: The 'oldKey' is the key you want to change. For instance, if you wanted to, you could get all keys from the session storage using `Object.keys(sessionStorage)` and loop over each key to append '1234::' to the start of it. You would call `appendToKey(oldKey)` when you wanted to change the key.